# Perl for Windows without the bells and whistles

Tags: windows-7, perl

I downloaded Strawberry Perl and, while it's useful, I want to run perl scripts on a second computer (actually, a production server), and I don't need the IDE or any special modules.  I just want to be able to run perl scripts that are already written.  In my searches, I found references to ActivePerl, but it's not clear to me if that's what I want.  What exactly should I download/install in order to simply run perl scripts?  The scripts I have in mind are nothing fancy, just some manipulation of text files with output to other files.

Answer (score 0):

Both suits you if you say you don't really care about modules. Both of them are designed for Windows. So I have nothing particular can tell about.

But if you suddenly want to download modules some days in the future, personally I would suggest ActivePerl, as the learning curve to using `ppm` (Perl Package Manager) install modules is much easier than using `cpan`, from a really really beginner perspective. And note, ActivePerl provide both `ppm` and `cpan` interface, where Strawberry Perl only have `cpan`

Finally, if you really want to dig in more, take a look at : http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=954413
(both have their draw backs, of cause)